# Is it possible to tag data by directory (path) in logstash?

Tags: logstash

I have following path: `~/somepath/en-us/somepath/file.json`

Is it possible to say smth like use following paths: `~/somepath/([a-z]{2}-[a-z]{2})/somepath/file.json` and use selected locale as tag in logstash?

Although given question as duplicate does not give working solution.. I will be glad to hear other advises...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extracting fields from input file path logstash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24053849/extracting-fields-from-input-file-path-logstash)

Comment: @Alcanzar given question (and its answer) as duplicate does not work. It has even not correct syntax.