# Creating Index based on pattern matching in logstash

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

I'm trying to build a centralised logging system for a group  windows & linux servers using elasticsearch logstash and kibana. My input would be syslogs from both the system(single input stream). I'm trying to understand if there is way to use grok and match the pattern and then based on that put the logs in different indices(one for windows logs and one for linux logs)

Any help in direction would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can assign 'type' based on from which system the logs are coming and then use that type in output.

Below is the configuration:

```
input{
   file{
     path =>"path/to/system1_log_file"
     type =>"sys1logs"
   }

  file{
    path =>"path/to/system2_log_files"
    type =>"sys2logs"
  }
}

output{
  if[type]=="sys1logs"{
  #output to sys1 index
   elasticsearch{host => localhost
               index => "sys1"
               }
   }

 if[type]=="sys2logs"{
 #output to sys2 index
  elasticsearch{host => localhost
               index =>"sys2"
              }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply @Ana! But my input is a single source(same path), hence I can't differentiate at the source. I would need to parse the logs and then put them into different indices

Comment: Look at the answer for [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24053849/extracting-fields-from-input-file-path-logstash). This might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can grok{} them and add_field when the grok matches:

```
grok {
    matches => { "message", "foo %{WORD}" }
    add_field => { "send_to", "fooindex" }
}
```

or from a field in the pattern:

```
grok {
    matches => { "message", "foo %{WORD:send_to} bar" }
}
```

And then use %{send_to} in your output:

```
elasticsearch {
    index => "%{send_to}-YYYY.MM.dd"
}
```

Note that if your indexes aren't named "logstash-*", you won't get the default mapping that logstash provides.