# Creating Index based on another field in logstash

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

this question was asked 3 months ago. One of the answers helped me but doesn't solve evey issues.

I am new to ELK and I have an issue to build the index based on another field.

Alain Collins solution (see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31277641/creating-index-based-on-pattern-matching-in-logstash/33435089?noredirect=1#31280446)) is pretty good: I could format the index as I wanted but the `send_to` field appears in the output and the field cannot be removed. `send_to` acts as a temporary variable used in the index. Is there any way to not output the `send_to` field ?

Answer (score 1):

Sure - use a relatively new feature called [metadata](https://www.elastic.co/blog/logstash-metadata).

Put the value in a field like [@metadata][send_to], which you can then refer to in the output stanza.  metadata fields aren't sent to elasticsearch, so they won't "pollute" your documents.

Comment: Wow, an answer from the man himself =). Thank you! I wasn't quite sure about the point of metadata; now I know.